# How To Change Wordpress REST API date into “time ago” format in Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, wordpress-rest-api

I would like to change the DATE FORMAT from the wordpress rest api - I have the following code:

```html
<div class="post-item">
  <div id="posts">Loading posts...</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://mysite.io/blog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed&per_page=3',
    success: function(data) {
      var posts_html = '';
      $.each(data, function(index, post) {
        posts_html += '<div class="post-item-image">';
        posts_html += '<a href="' + post.source_url + '"></a>';
        posts_html += '<img src="' + +'"</div>';
        posts_html += '<div class="post-item-header">';
        posts_html += '<span class="date">' + post.date + '</span>';
        posts_html += '<span class="user">';
        posts_html += '<a href="' + post.link + '">';
        posts_html += '<img src="https://mysite.io/images/users/mysite-1548344709.jpg">Mysites</a></span></div>';
        posts_html += '<div class="post-item-body">';
        posts_html += '<a href="' + post.link + '" style="text-decoration: underline;"> ' + post.title.rendered + '</a>';
        posts_html += '<div class="post-short-text"> ' + post.excerpt.rendered + '</div></div>';
      });
      $('#posts').html(posts_html);
    },
    error: function(request, status, error) {
      alert(error);
    }
  });
});
```

The problem is I now get this date format 2019-05-20T19:15:42 from:

```
posts_html += '<span class="date">' + post.date + '</span>';
```

I would like to change it to e.g. `3 days ago` OR exact date `20 May 2019`. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can format the date either on the server side in PHP or client side in JS. See either of the duplicates I marked for details on how to do this.

Comment: You can use Carbon. Parse this time with carbon and then use diffForHumans();

Comment: Carbon\Carbon::parse(' 2019-05-20T19:15:42'); should help :-)

Comment: How you can do that exactly with carbon?